# Why am I getting a wrong result from this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to create a simple search script.

So I wrote the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM snm_content
WHERE
    state = 1 AND
    `catid` NOT IN ('15', '23') AND
    `title` LIKE '%test%' OR `introtext` LIKE '%test%' OR `fulltext` LIKE '%test%'
```

The first check, `WHERE state = 1` fails, I get a result with a state of `-2`. How can that be?

This is my result when I use the query in PHPmyadmin:

[image]

How can I still get that result when clearly writing `state` needs to be `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses:

```
SELECT *
FROM snm_content
WHERE
    state = 1 AND
    catid NOT IN (15, 23) AND
    (title LIKE '%test%' OR introtext LIKE '%test%' OR fulltext LIKE '%test%');
```

Because of order of operations rules, your current `WHERE` clause is being interpreted as this:

```
WHERE
    ((state = 1 AND
    catid NOT IN (15, 23)) AND
    title LIKE '%test%') OR introtext LIKE '%test%' OR fulltext LIKE '%test%';
```

That is, the `title` field would have to match the wildcard expression in order for anything to be returned.

By the way, if you are trying to match the literal word `test` inside these fields, then consider using `REGEXP` with word boundaries:

```
SELECT *
FROM snm_content
WHERE
    state = 1 AND
    catid NOT IN (15, 23) AND
    (title REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR introtext REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]' OR
     fulltext REGEXP '[[:<:]]test[[:>:]]');
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to apply your OR Clauses within parentheses

```
SELECT * FROM snm_content WHERE state = 1 AND `catid` NOT IN ('15', '23') AND 
(`title` LIKE '%test%' OR `introtext` LIKE '%test%' OR `fulltext` LIKE '%test%')
```